# using compareandswap() to implement thread safe linkedlist

Tags: c++, thread-safety, linked-list

im attempting to understand thread safety. imagine im implementing a simple linked list (just an example im familiar with) and i have a function that deletes a given node from the list. ive been told about the function

int CompareAndSwap(int *address, int oldvalue, int newvalue);

and that this is what i must use to ensure thread safety, the only way i can imagine how to use to would be to send the memory addresses of nodes for oldvalue and newvalue but casting from node pointer to int loses precision and causes a compiler error so obviously im using it wrong.

could someone please give me an example of how to use it in this instance? thanks.

Comment: You would probably have to manipulate several pointers to manage a linked list. In that case it doesn't help if you can change a single pointer atomically.

Comment: @Bo Actually most thread safe linked lists are implemented with an atomic pointer sized cas. You initialize the new node completely before linking it into the list, if the next value has changed in between, the CAS fails and you start anew. Obviously here the problem is that the CAS has to be pointer sized for the simple solution - with an int that won't work. If we only have ints available, we can go for the array indizes linked list version - that gets pretty complicated when it has to grow though.

Comment: @Voo was my initial assumption on how to use the function accurate? are you saying i need function arguments of a larger datatype?

Comment: @humming I added another possible solution, but yes as a beginner you really should go for the right CAS version. I think c++11 added some CAS to the stdlib, before that you had to use the right libraries. There's a `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` under windows and I know that gcc has some built-ins for it, etc.